# Drop down being hidden behind banner button

Tags: css, z-index, drop-down-menu

On [this site](http://mcael.missionmedia.net), when user hovers over nav menu title "About MCAEL" the last nav title in the drop down is hiding underneath the left arrow button.

I've added z-index: 2000 to various portions in the nav css (i.e. #nav #nav ul & nav ul li), as well changed the button's z-index to 1, but still in modern browsers the drop down is hiding behind that button.  Oddly enough in ie6 & 7 there isnt an issue.

Any ideas and or suggestions to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add z-index: -1 to your main_body div, it works.

By the way, I checked in FF 3.6 and Chrome 8.

Comment: Thanks Jared!  That did it.  Maybe I could also ask you why in IE6 & 7 when user hovers over a nav title the drop downs are seen not beneath selected nav title but to the right?

Comment: My knee jerk reaction is that they are crummy browsers with too many bugs to count, but I think the actual problem is related to how IE6 and 7 handle positioning and z-index. http://www.gobdg.com/blog/2009/04/positionrelative-z-index-ie-bug/

Comment: Also, can you mark it as the answer (the check under the answer vote count)?

Comment: Thanks! :) Positioning and z-index are a pain. That site looks nice, too.